# Ordered Permutation of List<Int>

Tags: c#, permutation

Given an ordered list of integers, L = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
and a permutation size of k,

I need to generate all 'ordered' permutations of length k having the first sequence = L[0].

With the example above, this should yield the following results:

> **k = 1**
>
> = { 1 }
>
> **k = 2**
>
> = { 1, 2 }, { 1, 3 }, { 1, 4 }
>
> **k = 3**
>
> = { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 4}, { 1, 3, 4}
>
> **k = 4**
>
> = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }

This is what I came up with:

1. Assign permutations = Generate all possible permutations of L[1...n-1].
2. permutations.EliminateIfNotInOrder().
3. Prepend L[0] with each sequence in permutations.

Is there any better way to generate all ordered permutations in the first place, without needing the second-step of elimination?

Comment: It's going to be inefficient to generate permutations that you just filter out. Maybe there is a way to create only the permutations that are actually in order... There are `a = n - 1` possibilities for the second number in the sequence and then `a - 1` possibilities for the third number.

Comment: Why must all the results start with the minimum element of `L`? I.e. why doesn't `{2}` count as an ordered permutation of length 1?  Likewise why doesn't `{2, 3}` count as an ordered permutation of length 2?

Comment: @SumnerEvans yes the optimization part is what I'm currently still working on. It works out well with elimination, but I haven't been able to figure out the best way to generate an 'ordered' permutation in the first place. Any leads to proceed with this?

Comment: @Kyle it's a variation of permutation problem. I would consider only dealing with L[1..n-1]. The main problem is getting P, where P = ordered_permutations(L[1..n-1]). Then it's a matter of prepending L[0] with each sequence in P.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that by "in order" you mean matching the order in the initial list:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>( T value )
{
    yield return value;
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetOrderedPermutations<T>( IEnumerable<T> source, int k )
{
    if( k == 0 ) return new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };

    int length = source.Count();

    if( k == length ) return new[] { source };

    if( k > length ) return Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<T>>();

    return GetOrderedHelper<T>( source, k, length );
}

private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetOrderedHelper<T>( IEnumerable<T> source, int k, int length )
{
    if( k == 0 )
    {
        yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        yield break;
    }
    int i = 0;
    foreach( var item in source )
    {
        if( i + k > length ) yield break;
        var permutations = GetOrderedHelper<T>( source.Skip( i + 1 ), k - 1, length - i );
        i++;

        foreach( var subPerm in permutations )
        {
            yield return Yield( item ).Concat( subPerm );
        }
    }
}
```

This can still be made more efficient (by removing the recursion).  But this is the most straight-forward algorithm I could come up with.  In your case, since you always want the first element to appear, you can run the algorithm by chopping off the first element and just put it back on later:

```
var permutations = GetOrderedPermutations( source.Skip( 1 ), k - 1 )
    .Select( p => Yield( source.First() ).Concat( p ) );
```

The idea behind this algorithm is fairly simple: All permutations are found by picking the first item in the permutation and just prepending it to all permutations of length `k - 1` made out of the remainder of the list.

If you want to remove the recursion, there's a way of looking at it iteratively:

If you want a permutation of length `k`, initialize `k` pointers pointing to the first `k` elements of the source.  These pointers point to the elements of the current permutation.  To get the next permutation, increment the last pointer.  If the last pointer goes past the end of the source, increment the previous pointer and set the last pointer to one past it.  In code:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetOrderedPermutations<T>( IList<T> source, int k )
{
    if( k == 0 ) yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    if( k == source.Count ) yield return source;
    if( k > source.Count ) yield break;
    var pointers = Enumerable.Range( 0, k ).ToArray();

    // The first element of our permutation can only be in the first
    // Count - k + 1 elements.  If it moves past here, we can't have
    // anymore permutations because there aren't enough items in the list.
    while( pointers[0] <= source.Count - k )
    {
        yield return pointers.Select( p => source[p] );
        // Increment the last pointer
        pointers[k - 1]++;

        // The i variable will keep track of which pointer
        // we need to increment.  Start it at the second to
        // last (since this is the one that we're going to
        // increment if the last pointer is past the end).
        int i = k - 2;
        while( pointers[k - 1] >= source.Count && i >= 0 )
        {
            // Okay, the last pointer was past the end, increment
            pointers[i]++;

            // Reset all the pointers after pointer i
            for( int j = i + 1; j < k; ++j )
            {
                pointers[j] = pointers[j - 1] + 1;
            }

            // If the last pointer is still past the end, we'll
            // catch it on the next go-around of this loop.
            // Decrement i so we move the previous pointer next time.

            --i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works out really good! The second solution looks more complex, but will try to compare the performance between the two. Thank you so much!

Comment: @KenDTimothy In terms of actual lines of code the second solution is actually simpler ;).  But seriously it should perform much better than the recursive solution.  The recursive solution is actually going to use a lot more memory to do its work where the iterative one won't.  The iterative one is actually constant space, so it'll result in a lot less memory pressure (and I think recursive `yield` state machines end up causing some sort of undesirable quadratic behavior anyway, I can't remember).