# How do I get all non-overlapping permutations for a series of time blocks?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I have what seems to be a simple problem that I am having a hard time modeling in code (C#) -

I am trying to find the highest potential credit hours available to a person attending a conference. Courses have time blocks, such as Security 101 @ 9AM-10AM, Finance 202 @ 4PM-6PM, etc.

The main rule is, you can't attend two courses at once - so you would get credit for courses at 9-10 and 10-11, but you could not also get credit for a course that ran for 9-11.

What I would like to do is the following:

I would like to get an array of valid (valid meaning non-overlapping) paths throughout a day.

So, for example, the full set of courses for a day may be the following:

```
|---------------------------------------------------|
| COURSE            |   START       |   END         |
|-------------------|---------------|---------------|
| FINANCE 101       |   9:00 AM     |   10:00 AM    |
| FINANCE 102       |   10:00 AM    |   11:00 AM    |
| PYTHON 300        |   10:00 AM    |   11:00 AM    |
| SECURITY 101      |   11:00 AM    |   12:00 PM    |
| ECONOMICS 101     |   9:00 AM     |   12:00 PM    |
| DATABASE 200      |   11:00 AM    |   1:00 PM     |
|---------------------------------------------------|
```

There are a few paths someone might take throughout this day:

- `FINANCE 101 (9-10) -> FINANCE 102 (10-11) -> SECURITY 101 (11-12) -> DONE`
- `FINANCE 101 (9-10) -> PYTHON 300 (10-11) -> SECURITY 101 (11-12) -> DONE`
- `FINANCE 101 (9-10) -> FINANCE 102 (10-11) -> DATABASE 200 (11-1) -> DONE`
- `FINANCE 101 (9-10) -> PYTHON 300   (10-11) -> DATABASE 200 (11-1) -> DONE`
- `ECONOMICS 101 (9-12)-> DONE`

This is a somewhat simple scenario, in reality it would be possible to have multiple branching scenarios, such as having three 9-10 courses that would create more permutations on top of this.

The reason I would like an array of paths (instead of one single optimal path) is because there isn't necessarily a direct 1 Hour = 1 Credit Hour correlation, there would be a second level calculation based on the set of paths to sum the credit hour value of the path to determine what is 'best'.

My question is this - is there a technique or software pattern that I can follow in order to generate these permutations so that I can measure the results to determine the path that would yield the most credits for a course-taker?

### Edited for Solution:

Thanks everyone for your input and help, both solutions from [Bradley Uffner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526724/bradley-uffner) and [Xiaoy312](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561113/xiaoy312) nailed it!

[image]

Comment: So your objective is to find the 'optimal path', as opposed to, say, check if a person has taken (or submitted, really) two courses that overlap?

Comment: The ultimate goal is trying to find the optimal path, but to do that there is a second level of comparison (as the credit hour values don't necessarily equate to 1HR = 1 Credit Hour). If I can get the permutations of potential paths through a day, I can calculate the credit values for each to determine what is optimal.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I am pretty sure that your task can be solved with [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). If I am not mistaken your task is identical to the [knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) one.

Comment: @Evan Can we assume that the course starts and ends on `n:00`? Or, we might have to take minutes into account?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 in which case it may be perceived as a _set of requirements_ thus too broad

Comment: @Xiaoy312 assuming `n:00` isn't safe, a course could be potentially an hour and half, so `9:00-10:30` would be possible for sure.

Comment: And, to find an optimal solution you must have a start and end time? Like from 9:00 to 17:00 or similar?

Comment: @Sach Right, so in the example, the possible solutions all start at 9 and end at either 12 or 1, depending on what they may take next without overlapping with another course (i.e. being two places at the same time)

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear. What I meant was, is there a solid being and end time that courses should fall within, or does the boundary depend on your data. That is, if your data goes from 9AM to 1PM, then anything goes between those two, but if your min and max of existing data is 8AM and 3PM, then that would be your interval?

Comment: @Sach Ah I see, the boundaries depend on the data, there is no set start or end - that could potentially differ on each 'path' through the data.

Comment: is validation part of the problem? ie., do you need to check for overlaps and then either abort or make sure overlapping parts are counted just once; or can you assume that your input data will already be clean of overlaps?

Comment: @dlatikay Validation is part of the problem yes - because these are courses at a conference, a person cannot physically be at two places at once, so overlaps must be avoided. A person may choose to go to a course from 9a-10a, or they may choose to go to a course at 9a-10:30a - either choice is valid itself, but they cannot attend both. The one they choose will impact the next course they may take, and that choice may impact the next, so on and so forth. I'm looking to get all of these permutations, then evaluate each for their 'credit value', which may not correlate with physical hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will just recursively walk through the list of courses, picking any courses that start on or after the end of the last course taken.

It probably isn't as efficient as @Xiaoy312's answer, but it shows another method.  I've also added course credits, displaying the total credit for a particular path, as well as selecting the optimal path.

This could be cleanup up significantly by adding a proper `CourseLoad` class to store the class list instead of using `List<>` and `List<List<>>`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoursePath
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var courses = new List<CourseInfo>()
                          {
                              new CourseInfo("Finance 101", 1, DateTime.Parse("9:00 AM"), DateTime.Parse("10:00 AM")),
                              new CourseInfo("Finance 102", 2, DateTime.Parse("10:00 AM"), DateTime.Parse("11:00 AM")),
                              new CourseInfo("Python 300", 3, DateTime.Parse("10:00 AM"), DateTime.Parse("11:00 AM")),
                              new CourseInfo("Security 101", 4, DateTime.Parse("11:00 AM"), DateTime.Parse("12:00 PM")),
                              new CourseInfo("Economics 201", 5, DateTime.Parse("9:00 AM"), DateTime.Parse("12:00 PM")),
                              new CourseInfo("Database 200", 6, DateTime.Parse("11:00 AM"), DateTime.Parse("1:00 PM"))
                          };

            var results = new List<List<CourseInfo>>();

            BuildCourseList(null, courses, results);

            results.ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" -> ", c.Select(x => x.Name)) + $" -> Done ({c.Sum(x => x.Credits)} credits)"));
            Console.WriteLine();
            var optimal = results.Select(path => new {Path = path, TotalCredits = path.Sum(c => c.Credits)}).OrderByDescending(path => path.TotalCredits).First();
            Console.WriteLine("Optimal Path: " + string.Join(" -> ", optimal.Path.Select(x => x.Name)) + $" -> Done ({optimal.TotalCredits} credits)");
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static void BuildCourseList(List<CourseInfo> currentPath, List<CourseInfo> courses, List<List<CourseInfo>> results)
        {
            CourseInfo currentCourse = currentPath?.LastOrDefault();
            var candidates = (currentCourse == null ? courses : courses.Where(c => c.StarTime >= currentCourse.EndTime));
            if (currentPath != null)
            {
                results.Add(currentPath);
            }
            foreach (var course in candidates)
            {
                var nextPath = currentPath == null ? new List<CourseInfo>() : new List<CourseInfo>(currentPath);
                nextPath.Add(course);
                BuildCourseList(nextPath, courses, results);
            }
        }
    }

    public class CourseInfo
    {
        public CourseInfo(string name, int credits, DateTime starTime, DateTime endTime)
        {
            Name = name;
            Credits = credits;
            StarTime = starTime;
            EndTime = endTime;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }
        public DateTime StarTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Finance 101 -> Done (1 credits)
Finance 101 -> Finance 102 -> Done (3 credits)
Finance 101 -> Finance 102 -> Security 101 -> Done (7 credits)
Finance 101 -> Finance 102 -> Database 200 -> Done (9 credits)
Finance 101 -> Python 300 -> Done (4 credits)
Finance 101 -> Python 300 -> Security 101 -> Done (8 credits)
Finance 101 -> Python 300 -> Database 200 -> Done (10 credits)
Finance 101 -> Security 101 -> Done (5 credits)
Finance 101 -> Database 200 -> Done (7 credits)
Finance 102 -> Done (2 credits)
Finance 102 -> Security 101 -> Done (6 credits)
Finance 102 -> Database 200 -> Done (8 credits)
Python 300 -> Done (3 credits)
Python 300 -> Security 101 -> Done (7 credits)
Python 300 -> Database 200 -> Done (9 credits)
Security 101 -> Done (4 credits)
Economics 201 -> Done (5 credits)
Database 200 -> Done (6 credits)

Optimal Path: Finance 101 -> Python 300 -> Database 200 -> Done (10 credits)
```

Comment: You can add an `if (currentPath !=null)` around the `results.Add` in `BuildCourseList`, and then you can remove the awkward null-check in `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: Thank you, that was bothering me.

Comment: I've updated the code to also select and display the optimal path.

Answer (score 4):

Answer adapted from [Ordered Permutation of List<Int>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840771/ordered-permutation-of-listint):

```
public static class CourseExtensions
{    
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Course>> GetPermutations(this IEnumerable<Course> courses)
    {
        return GetCoursesHelper(courses, TimeSpan.Zero);
    }
    private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Course>> GetCoursesHelper(IEnumerable<Course> courses, TimeSpan from)
    {        
        foreach (var course in courses)
        {
            if (course.Start < from) continue;

            yield return new[] { course };

            var permutations = GetCoursesHelper(courses, course.End);
            foreach (var subPermutation in permutations)
            {
                yield return new[]{ course }.Concat(subPermutation);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
void Main()
{
    foreach (var courses in GetCourses().GetPermutations())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" -> ", courses
            .Select(x => x.ToString())
            .Concat(new [] { "DONE" })));
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Course
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Start { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan End { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} ({1:hhmm}-{2:hhmm})",
           Name, Start, End);
    }
}

IEnumerable<Course> GetCourses() 
{
    var data = @"
| FINANCE 101       |   9:00 AM     |   10:00 AM    |
| FINANCE 102       |   10:00 AM    |   11:00 AM    |
| PYTHON 300        |   10:00 AM    |   11:00 AM    |
| SECURITY 101      |   11:00 AM    |   12:00 PM    |
| ECONOMICS 101     |   9:00 AM     |   12:00 PM    |
| DATABASE 200      |   11:00 AM    |   1:00 PM     |
".Trim();

    return data.Split('\n')
        .Select(r => r.Split('|').Select(c => c.Trim()).ToArray())
        .Select(x => new Course
        {
            Name = x[1],
            Start = DateTime.ParseExact(x[2], "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay,
            End = DateTime.ParseExact(x[3], "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay
        });
}

public static class CourseExtensions
{    
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Course>> GetPermutations(this IEnumerable<Course> courses)
    {
        return GetCoursesHelper(courses, TimeSpan.Zero);
    }
    private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Course>> GetCoursesHelper(IEnumerable<Course> courses, TimeSpan from)
    {        
        foreach (var course in courses)
        {
            if (course.Start < from) continue;

            yield return new[] { course };

            var permutations = GetCoursesHelper(courses, course.End);
            foreach (var subPermutation in permutations)
            {
                yield return new[]{ course }.Concat(subPermutation);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
FINANCE 101 (0900-1000) -> DONE
FINANCE 101 (0900-1000) -> FINANCE 102 (1000-1100) -> DONE
FINANCE 101 (0900-1000) -> FINANCE 102 (1000-1100) -> SECURITY 101 (1100-1200) -> DONE
FINANCE 101 (0900-1000) -> FINANCE 102 (1000-1100) -> DATABASE 200 (1100-1300) -> DONE
FINANCE 101 (0900-1000) -> PYTHON 300 (1000-1100) -> DONE
FINANCE 101 (0900-1000) -> PYTHON 300 (1000-1100) -> SECURITY 101 (1100-1200) -> DONE
FINANCE 101 (0900-1000) -> PYTHON 300 (1000-1100) -> DATABASE 200 (1100-1300) -> DONE
FINANCE 101 (0900-1000) -> SECURITY 101 (1100-1200) -> DONE
FINANCE 101 (0900-1000) -> DATABASE 200 (1100-1300) -> DONE
FINANCE 102 (1000-1100) -> DONE
FINANCE 102 (1000-1100) -> SECURITY 101 (1100-1200) -> DONE
FINANCE 102 (1000-1100) -> DATABASE 200 (1100-1300) -> DONE
PYTHON 300 (1000-1100) -> DONE
PYTHON 300 (1000-1100) -> SECURITY 101 (1100-1200) -> DONE
PYTHON 300 (1000-1100) -> DATABASE 200 (1100-1300) -> DONE
SECURITY 101 (1100-1200) -> DONE
ECONOMICS 101 (0900-1200) -> DONE
DATABASE 200 (1100-1300) -> DONE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can represent your data as a graph with vertices - courses (time periods) connected *iff* their time periods are overlapping. Then your problems turns into finding maximal independent sets of vertices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)

If you want all day plans you get:

> The **maximal independent set listing** problem: the input is an undirected graph, and the output is a list of all its maximal independent sets.

If each of your courses (vertices) has a weight value then you get:

> The **maximum-weight independent set** problem: the input is an undirected graph with weights on its vertices and the output is an independent set with maximum total weight