# How to find the longest (time-wise) sequence of non-overlapping DateTime ranges in an unordered set of DateTime ranges?

Tags: c#, .net, sequence, overlapping

I had a programming test not so long ago, and I got puzzled with that problem: finding out the longest (basically considering the sum or  non overlapping activities, with activities defined by:

```
public class Activity
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public DateTime Start { get; }
    public DateTime Stop { get; }
    public TimeSpan Duration => Stop - Start;

    private Activity(string name, DateTime start, DateTime stop)
    {
        if (start > stop)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(start));
        }

        Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        Start = start;
        Stop = stop;
    }
}
```

And used in something like that:

```
public class LongestNonOverlappingActivitySequenceFinder
{
    public IEnumerable<Activity> Find(IEnumerable<Activity> activities)
    {
        // Logic goes here...
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var reference = DateTime.Today.AddHours(0);
        var activites = new[]
        {
            new Activity("A", reference, reference.AddHours(1)),
            new Activity("B", reference.AddHours(1), reference.AddHours(2)),
            new Activity("C", reference.AddHours(1), reference.AddHours(1.5)),
            new Activity("D", reference.AddHours(2), reference.AddHours(3)),
        };

        foreach (var activity in LongestNonOverlappingActivitySequenceFinder.FindLongestNonOverlappingRangeSet(activites))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(activity.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

The solution I used during the is something like what is suggested here: [How do I get all non-overlapping permutations for a series of time blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005810/how-do-i-get-all-non-overlapping-permutations-for-a-series-of-time-blocks)

But it's recursive + quite greedy, basically that was my solution for the test, but it kept timeout.

Notes before going to bed:

- Can support gaps between two activities as long as the cumulated duration of all the activities is the longest and without overlapping
- If there is a single long activity which has a duration equal to the sum of non-overlapping activities durations, then we pick up this set of non overlapping activities (the idea is to schedule as many activities as possible).

Comment: I assume you mean longest in total duration? So it might well be that just a single activity represents the longest possible sequence, even if there's another sequence of several activities with a smaller total duration.

Comment: Also I assume it's only a sequence if there's no gaps - i.e. if there's 2 activities that make up the longest sequence, the start time of the 2nd activity must equal the end time of the 1st?

Comment: Not necessarily actually, as long as the cumulated duration of all the activities durations is the longest one.

Comment: Hmm, then I wouldn't really consider it a sequence. Are you saying if there's 3 activities, one starting at s with length 1h, the next one starting at s+24h with length 3h, and then some overlapping activities, and finally one starting at s+48 with length 2hrs, then the longest sequence is the first two activities, with cumulative duration 3hrs, even though they're spread over 27 hrs?

Comment: It doesn't matter, criteria are: 1) longest cumulated activities duration 2) maximum number of activities for that duration

Comment: Out of curiosity how long were you given to find a solution?  I'm always looking for new test ideas but this isn't really something I'd expect anyone to solve in under a couple of hours.

Comment: Got 1.5 hours, sadly my permutations trick was real slow :x Fun part some of the criteria you asked were not even mentioned in the description... when I was taking the test. Got 74 percent success rate (most likely due to other exercises) but still I think there must be a better solution than just generating all the non overlapping permutations + durarions sum check + activities count check...

Comment: Even using the Heap's Algorithm for permutations generation is still O(N!)...