# Get Items that sum Closest to Given Value

Tags: c#

I have a list of values. lets say they're {1,2,3,4,5}

and I want to find the combination that sums closest to a given value

so for example if i entered 8 then the function could return 
either {3,5} or {1,3,4}. either of those would be exact and i would just take the one with the least indexes 3+5

if there isn't a value that is exact for example 9.45 it would return the value 
closest without going over the threshold {4,5}

I'm not sure where i would even start with this. i think it may be possible with a linq query...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Answer (score 0):

```
    static IEnumerable<int> GetClosestValues(IReadOnlyList<int> c, int t)
    {
        var s=0m;
        return c.Select((x, i) => i).OrderByDescending(i => c[i]).Where(i => (s += c[i]) <= t).OrderBy(i => i);
    }
```

Seems to work... not optimized though

Answer (score 0):

The key is just to find all permutations of the set, and then filter (less or equal than threshold value) and order (by distance to threshold value, then by size of the set) them via LINQ:

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => (double)x).ToArray();
var permutations = Enumerable.Range(1, source.Length)
    .SelectMany(x => Utils.GetOrderedPermutations(source, x))
    .Dump();
var threshold = 9.45;

var result = permutations
    .Select(x => x.ToArray())
    .Select(x => new { Set = x, Sum = x.Sum() })
    .Where(x => x.Sum <= threshold)
    .OrderBy(x => threshold - x.Sum)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Set.Length)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .Dump();
```

---

`GetOrderedPermutations` is taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42842770):

```
public class Utils
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(T value)
    {
        yield return value;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetOrderedPermutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int k)
    {
        if (k == 0) return new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };

        int length = source.Count();

        if (k == length) return new[] { source };

        if (k > length) return Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<T>>();

        return GetOrderedHelper<T>(source, k, length);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetOrderedHelper<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int k, int length)
    {
        if (k == 0)
        {
            yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
            yield break;
        }
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (i + k > length) yield break;
            var permutations = GetOrderedHelper<T>(source.Skip(i + 1), k - 1, length - i);
            i++;

            foreach (var subPerm in permutations)
            {
                yield return Yield(item).Concat(subPerm);
            }
        }
    }
}
```